# How do I figure out the second set of clues in Infamous: Paper Trail Part 2?

Tags: infamous-paper-trail

I figured out that the name is Paulson I just can't find the case number. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

It's in the writing on the web page. Go through and every word that has a number replacing a letter write the number down. then go on the DUP intranet and put in the numbers you found. it will bring up a video with a different case number above it this case number is what you need.